# Deleting all files & directories except those matching a given glob pattern

Tags: java, file, glob, delete-file, fileutils

I have a list of all the files & directories that I need to delete, but I need to exclude all files/directories that match a given [glob](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=77d52406e5b8042cJmltdHM9MTY3NjUwNTYwMCZpZ3VpZD0xMTMyNzhiMC03MWE0LTY4ODgtMDkxZS02OTY5NzA1NjY5MWEmaW5zaWQ9NTIwNw&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=113278b0-71a4-6888-091e-69697056691a&psq=glob+java&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9zdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmNvbS9xdWVzdGlvbnMvMjQ2Nzc2NjIvbWF0Y2gtcGF0aC1zdHJpbmctdXNpbmctZ2xvYi1pbi1qYXZh&ntb=1) pattern. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

I am currently using the FileUtils class to delete files like this -

```
for (File path : cleanableFiles) {
            try {
                FileUtils.deleteQuietly(path);
                FileUtils.deleteDirectory(path);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
            }
        }
```

cleanableFiles is `Set<File>`. I also have a glob pattern string (e.g  '*.txt' to match all files that have .txt extension). I need to not delete the files/directories that match the glob pattern.

Comment: The Q&A you link to would seem to answer your question. Or are you asking this because, for some reason, you are not allowed to use the `java.nio.file` API?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in Java by using the java.nio.file.Files and java.nio.file.Path classes, and by using the java.nio.file.FileSystem class to create a PathMatcher that can match against a glob pattern.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.PathMatcher;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
```